# Facing an exception while using Excel 2007 sheet as database in C# windows application

Tags: c#, ado.net, excel-2007, oledb

I am trying to fetch information Excel 2007 document, suppose my code is as given below:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path+  " ; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES");
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Name from Table$ where Number = "+textBox1.Text +"",con);
label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
con.Close();
```

Now on `con.open();` I am getting Exception as `Could not find installable ISAM.`

what does this mean and what should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805)?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes around the datasource and double quotes around the Extended Properties:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" + path+  "'; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\"");
```

also check the installed JET version:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114/en-us
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805/en-us